# How to print a list with x (column) and y (row) property into a table?

Tags: c#

Say I have this class below

```
public class Seat
{
    public int Row { get; }
    public int Col { get; }
    public EnumStatus Status { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A valid seat object will always need row and col.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="row"></param>
    /// <param name="col"></param>
    public Seat(int row, int col)
    {
        Row = row;
        Col = col;
        Status = EnumStatus.Empty;
     }

    public enum EnumStatus
    {
        Empty, Taken
    }
}
```

and I have this method which create 30 seats object below

```
private void GenerateCompleteSeats()
    {
        int totalRow = 3;
        int totalCol = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalRow; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < totalCol; y++)
            {
                seats.Add(new Seat(i+1, y+1));
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I print out back the 30 seat object in 3 rows and 10 columns? Currently, I can only use foreach loop to print them all.

```
private void PrintSeatsDetails(List<Seat> _seats)
    {
        foreach (var item in _seats)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Row: {item.Row}. Col: {item.Col}. Status: {item.Status}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify? What's wrong with the foreach loop? Do you want to sort them by row then column before printing? What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: foreach loop is working fine but it generate 30 rows (actual output) of output instead of 3 (my expected output). I want the output to be based on Y (row) property.

Comment: The answer is in your second code block.

Comment: @jqsoft. How the second code block print what is stored in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I meant something like this:

```cs
var output = new List<string>();
int totalRow = 3;
int totalCol = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < totalRow; i++)
{
    var lines = seats.Skip(i * totalCol).Take(totalCol)
        .Select(seat => $"Row: {seat.Row}. Col: {seat.Col}. Status: {seat.Status}");

    output.Add(string.Join(" ", lines));
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", output));
```

Or maybe a better way like this:

```cs
var output = new StringBuilder();
int totalRow = 3;
int totalCol = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < totalRow; i++)
{
    seats.Skip(i * totalCol).Take(totalCol)
        .Select(seat => $"Row: {seat.Row}. Col: {seat.Col}. Status: {seat.Status} ")
        .ToList().ForEach(x => output.Append(x.Trim()));

    output.AppendLine();
}

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Where both code snippets use the [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8) and [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8) extension methods. So you have 3 rounds to create the three lines, each round will take the next 10 items from the `seats` list to concatenate their values in a single line and append it into the `output` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort your List, you can print out the rows individually with seats in the same row.

```
    private void PrintSeatsDetails(List<Seat> _seats)
    {
        //sorting by row because you don't know that the order of the seats are set
        _seats.Sort((a, b) => (a.Row.CompareTo(b.Row)));
        int curRow = -1;
        foreach (var item in _seats)
        {
            if (item.Row != curRow) {
                curRow = item.Row;
                Console.Write($"\nRow: {curRow}. ");
            }
            Console.Write($"Col: {item.Col}:{item.Status}. ");
        }
    }
```